# Vector Dummy Declaration

Tags: c++, c++17

A Vectors in C++ are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size. They use contiguous storage locations for their elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed using offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and just as efficiently as in arrays.

Can anyone explain to me, in easy layman language, what the meaning of `vector<int> dummy1(rows,-1);` is in C++? Specifically, what does `dummy1(rows,-1)` mean?

Comment: `dummy`/`dummy1` are just identifiers/names as any other. There is nothing special about them language-wise.

Answer (score 5):

The code is declaring and constructing an object named `dummy1` whose type is `vector<int>`, using [constructor #3 on this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to initialize the object with `rows` number of elements that are all set to the value `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is the number of elements, the second argument is the value used to fill all of those elements. So it creates a vector with `rows` number of elements, all with the value `-1`